# How to check if there's SQL injection vulnerability PROGRAMMATICALLY?

Tags: security, sql-injection

I see some hack tools can find web pages with SQL injection vulnerability AUTOMATICALLY.

How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one can make an educated guess about the SQL code structure, to allow the injection.

For example, with a vulnerable username/password verification code, it will be in most cases something like:

```
select count(*) from users where username=@username and password=@password;
```

so the hacker will attempt to inject something like:

```
@username=" 'blabla' or 1=1  "
@password=" 'blabla' or 1=1  "
```

so the result would be that count(*) will be > 0, hence login accepted.

Comment: But vulnerability discovery tools(not human) can't run SQL directly,it can only send requests to the web server,how to know whether an injection fails or not?

Comment: the hacker has to be creative. For example, if in the response page there is no longer the "login" textbox, it means the hack succeeded. The "vulnerability discovery tools" work similar to an hacker, and they can't cover all scenarios.

Comment: But as a tool,it never knows whether a page is a login page or not.

Comment: Also,the vulnerability can occure in any pages,not only the login page.I'm seeking for a general answer....

Answer (score 0):

An easy test can be to just put a single quote in the input field and see if you get a mysql error message back.

If you get something like 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''''' at line 1 '

or if you get a php/mysql error (which could probably be programmatically recognized by its formatting or the common error message) then you also know you have an injection vulnerability.

If you just get a generic 'no such username' or a valid empty result set back, then you most likely don't have an injection vulnerability.

Comment: This is NOT programmatical...And it'll never work if error messages are not displayed.

Comment: >This is NOT programmatical.

Sure it is. foreach input field on page: 1)post the form with a "\'" as the value. 2)if( found_php_or_mysql_error()): then we have a vulnerability
          
 -- found_php_or_mysql_error() could be implemented with some simple regexes

Comment: So it's based on that the error messages are outputed directly?

Comment: yes, many site programmed in php (and other interpreted languages) will still output error messages in the html, even in a production environment. This is **bad** from a security standpoint. If they've suppressed warnings and errors, than it gives you a lot less to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these tools have lists of parameters that are known to break web pages. They fire these parameters off in multiple requestsm inserting the parameters in:

1. form fields
2. the GET URL
3. HTTP Headers

Their tools will usually spider the site to ensure they are hitting as much of the site as possible.

One of the tricky bits is determining when you have found an exploitable web page. In some cases the web server might take longer to retuen the page, or certain parts of the page might be slightly different. Things to check for:

1. HTTP Response Codes (500 server error probably means SQL is invalid)
2. Size of returned page
3. Time taken for page to return

Having said all that, if you actually have access to the site's source code you can use static analysis techniques to look for vulnerabilites.

Comment: Can you elaborate on determining when you have found an exploitable web page PROGRAMMATICALLY?